# 和暦で年を表すjavascriptは？

Tags: javascript

和暦で年だけを表すjavascriptを頂けますでしょうか？

```
document.write(date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese"));
```

だと思いましたが違うみたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 行いたいことを見ると、`和暦→西暦`にしたいということでしょうか？それとも文字通り和暦の年号が表示したいのでしょうか？

Comment: 今年を西暦ではなく、和暦で表示させたいだけです。

Answer (score 4):

「違うみたい」というのを説明して頂けますか？
単に、年の部分を取り出すということなら`substring`と`indexOf`を使って`/`までを次の様にして切り出せます。

```js
var date = new Date();
date = date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese");
var year = date.substring(0, date.indexOf("/"));
document.write(year);
```

Comment: 私、書き方が違ってました。どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`toLocaleDateString`の第二引数で`era`を指定すればよいのでは。

```
date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era:"long" })
```

ただEdgeではこの指定だと`28/02/24`となり元号が出力されないようです。これが仕様なのか不具合なのかはわかりませんが、`平成`を得るには`day`が含まれないオプションにする必要があります。

```
date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era:"long", year:"numeric", month:"numeric" })
```

Comment: `toLocaleDateString` の仕様が少しややこしいのですが、locale データの中には「もっともらしい日付の表示」の候補がいくつかあります。和暦の場合、"平成28年5月10日火曜日" (full)、”平成28年5月10日" (long, medium)、"H28/5/10" (short) のいずれかになるはずです。`toLocateDateString` の formatmatcher オプションが `"best effort"` の場合、この中から一番もっともらしい(与えられた他のオプションに一番マッチする)日付フォーマットを選ぶことになります。

そもそもが和暦では元号なしのフォーマットを規定してないので、`era` の値がどうであれ元号が出ない時点で、Edge は locale データの取り扱いにバグがあるみたいですね。

Answer (score -3):

自動更新される場合は、次のようにもできるようです。

```
<script language="javaScript">
<!--
var now=new Date();
var Wareki=now.getYear();
if (Wareki>1000){Wareki -=1900;}
Wareki -=88;
document.write("<font style='font-size : 30px; color : red'>");
document.write("今年は平成");
document.write(Wareki);
document.write("年");
document.write("です</font>");
//-->
</script>
```

参考：http://tsunamiblog.blog60.fc2.com/blog-entry-74.html

Comment: これは単に平成の場合に西暦から自力で変換してるだけですね。平成元年の場合には使えないですし、平成が終わって次の元号に変わった場合も使えなくなってしまいます。

処理系や外部ライブラリにカレンダーデータがある場合はそちらを使うべきです。

Comment: もちろん自動更新ですので、"平成元年"に戻ることはありませんが、
次の元号に変わった場合に不備がありますね。
この記述の仕方は、"平成”のみに使える方法です。